# Use custom eslint config file in VSCode that is managed via Yarn

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, yarnpkg

I have eslint installed and running in VSCode, but it is not using our config file.

The settings I have changed are

```
{
  "eslint.nodePath": "C:\\Users\\PARAGON\\Documents\\AllCode\\ParagonCore\\clients\\utilities\\paragon-scripts\\node_modules",
  "eslint.options": {
    "configFile": "C:\\Users\\PARAGON\\Documents\\AllCode\\ParagonCore\\clients\\utilities\\paragon-scripts\\configuration\\.eslintrc.js",
  },
  "eslint.packageManager": "yarn",
}
```

UPDATE:

modified nodePath and fixed file path mistake

```
[Info  - 12:30:26 PM] ESLint library loaded from: 
C:\Users\PARAGON\AppData\Local\Yarn\config\global\node_modules\eslint\lib\api.js
[Error - 12:30:26 PM] Cannot read config file: C:\Users\PARAGON\Documents\AllCode\Paragon\ParagonCore\clients\utilities\paragon-scripts\configuration\.eslintrc.js Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\PARAGON\Documents\AllCode\Paragon\ParagonCore\clients\utilities\paragon-scripts\configuration\.eslintrc.js'
[Error - 12:32:56 PM] 
Failed to load plugin react: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'
Happened while validating C:\Users\PARAGON\Documents\AllCode\ParagonCore\clients\job-grid\source\scripts\components\AssignToUser.jsx
This can happen for a couple of reasons:
1. The plugin name is spelled incorrectly in an ESLint configuration file (e.g. .eslintrc).
2. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure 'eslint-plugin-react' is installed globally as well.
3. If ESLint is installed locally, then 'eslint-plugin-react' isn't installed correctly.

Consider running eslint --debug C:\Users\PARAGON\Documents\AllCode\ParagonCore\clients\job-grid\source\scripts\components\AssignToUser.jsx from a terminal to obtain a 
trace about the configuration files used.
```

---

```
Failed to load plugin react: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react'
Happened while validating C:\Users\PARAGON\Documents\AllCode\ParagonCore\clients\job-grid\source\scripts\components\controls\CreateJob.jsx
This can happen for a couple of reasons:
1. The plugin name is spelled incorrectly in an ESLint configuration file 
(e.g. .eslintrc).
2. If ESLint is installed globally, then make sure 'eslint-plugin-react' is 
installed globally as well.
3. If ESLint is installed locally, then 'eslint-plugin-react' isn't installed correctly.

Consider running eslint --debug 
C:\Users\PARAGON\Documents\AllCode\ParagonCore\clients\job-
grid\source\scripts\components\controls\CreateJob.jsx from a terminal to 
obtain a trace about the configuration files used.
```

Comment: Finding the eslint config file shouldn't have anything to do with which package manager you are using. Are you opening VSCode in a folder that is on the same level as the configuration folder?

Comment: @NathanBierema the open folder is 3 levels up

Comment: Sounds like it's having resolving the eslint module, not the configuration file. Make sure eslint is installed globally using Yarn if you use the `"eslint.packageManager": "yarn"` option.

Comment: You'll have to install `eslint-plugin-react` globally too it looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make sure you do not have the package installed globally. Then, set `"eslint.nodePath"` to the location of your `node_modules` directory that is parallel to the configuration directory.

1. `yarn global remove eslint`
2. `"eslint.nodePath": "C:/.../node_modules"`
3. open some files and look for "ESLint library loaded from:" in the Output window